# Embedding SFPX (SharePoint Framework) webparts in an iframe

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, iframe, sharepoint-framework

Wondering if others are having this issue.  I have an spfx webpart page that I'm embedding in an iFrame for one of our internal apps.  The webpart page on its own is perfectly fine, as soon as we put it in an iFrame its inconsistently failing to load with these errors in the console.

> "Unable to get property 'loadWebPart' of undefined or null reference"
>
> Can't load the application on this page. Use the browser Back button
>   to retry. If the problem persists, contact the administrator of the
>   site and give them the information in Technical Details.

Both site and app are out of the box to break it down to its core issue.

**No iframe**
[image: No iframe screenshot]
**With an iframe - the webpart fails to load**
[image]

Comment: Does this happen if you add a non-spfx based webpart to the iframed page?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I just tested with a non spfx webpart and it works fine.  Our workaround for the time being has been to iframe a page that redirects to the page with the spfx webpart.  Funny enough this solution is solid and works every time.